# Can't use temporary column in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
select  cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32)) 
            + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32)) 
            + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') as 'RowID' ,
            *
from    workflow.delegation_engine de
where   RowID <> NULL
```

When I try to execute the following I receive the error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Invalid column name 'RowID'.

Just wondering how I can reference this temporary column? I searched for previous postings which suggested using 'having' for this however that doesn't appear to work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution would be to make a subselect of the entire statement, applying the where clause on its result

```
select  *
from    (
          select  cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32)) 
                  + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32)) 
                  + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') as 'RowID'
                  , *
          from    workflow.delegation_engine de
        ) de 
where   de.RowID IS NOT NULL
```

---

Another solution could be to repeat the entire clause in the WHERE clause

```
select  cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') as 'RowID' ,
        *
from    workflow.delegation_engine de
where   cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') IS NOT NULL
```

---

Or you could test each individual field for NULL

```
select  cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32)) 
        + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') as 'RowID' ,
        *
from    workflow.delegation_engine de
where   de.ApprovalOrder IS NOT NULL
        AND de.EntityCode IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `<> NULL` will give the OP problems.  It is not the intended conditional clause, I believe.

Comment: +1 as Option3 is a more practical refactor of Option2, and often a more useful clause for the optimiser than Option1.  *[It may feel less elegant, but when it gives the optimiser more clues to reduce the execution plan, it's got legs, and I likes legs.]*

Comment: I agree but option #3 could be unwieldy with large queries that have multiple people across them over time - I definitely prefer it for something of this size though

Comment: @Codingo - And so we enter the world of performance vs maintenance.  Let us dance!

Comment: +1 for thinking outside of the question, and not just correcting a simple error but recommending a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

You'd either have to use the express in the `WHERE` clause, or use your `SELECT` query as a subquery, like so:

```
select *
from
(
    select  cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32))  
                + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32))  
                + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') as RowID, 
                * 
    from    workflow.delegation_engine de 
)
where RowID is not NULL
```

Or, the sloppier (in my opinion) route would be:

```
select  cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32))    
            + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32))    
            + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') as RowID,   
            *   
from    workflow.delegation_engine de   
where   cast(de.ApprovalOrder AS VARCHAR(32))    
            + cast(de.EntityCode AS VARCHAR(32))    
            + isnull(cast(de.DelegationCode AS VARCHAR(32)), '') is not null
```

I would go with the first solution every time.

Also notice that I've changed your `WHERE` clause from

```
RowID <> NULL
```

To

```
RowID is not NULL
```

This is because `<> NULL` will never evaluate to true.  SQL Server tests for `NULL` (i.e. unknown) using `IS` and `IS NOT`.

Comment: +1 Or use a CTE instead of a sub-query.  They're pretttttttty!

Comment: @Dems - oh please... go to bed... ;)

Comment: @Dems Haha :) That is a curious comment, though.  I wonder what the performance difference would be.  Let me test that out...

Comment: I would be surprised if there was one. For this case, it would simply be (subjective) better readable.

Comment: @Shark - Should be none, both the sub-query and CTE are just inline-views.  Lieven's third option, however, *can* have performance benefits depending on INDEXes by reducing the deriviation to SARGable components.

Comment: @Dems You are correct, the CTE and subquery have the exact same execution plan.