# How to use temporary column's name in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, ora-00904

First of all, I have to say that I had researched my question before came here and saw a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611620/cant-use-temporary-column-in-where-clause) and all its answers, but unfortunately it hasn't helped me.

Oracle SQL.

I have :

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    salary_dollars, 
    0.85 * salary_dollars AS salary_euro
FROM 
    employees 
WHERE 
    0.85 * salary_dollars > 4000;
```

Where the `salary_euro` is my temporary column. I want to avoid double computation in `WHERE` clause, but if i write `WHERE salary_euro > 4000` in my request then I get this error:

> ORA-00904: "SALARY_EURO": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 6 Column: 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way around this restriction is to use a subquery to create your temporary columns:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT first_name, 
               salary_dollars, 
               0.85 * salary_dollars AS salary_euro
       FROM    employees) e
WHERE  salary_euro > 4000;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mureinik, do we really need here 'e' ? Because it works without 'e' as well

Comment: That's an **alias** for the whole subquery (which acts as an inline view). It would make more sense if Mureinik used it in e.g. `where e.salary.euro > 4000` or in `select` statement's column list (instead of an asterisk). But yes, it works without it as well.

Comment: @StanlyT in Oracle SQL you don't strictly need it, as you noted. Some other RDMBSs require it, so I found it's a good practice to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle now supports *lateral join*s.  This allows you to move the definitions to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.salary_dollars, x.salary_euro    
FROM employees e CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT 0.85 * e.salary_dollars AS salary_euro FROM DUAL
     ) x
WHERE x.salary_euro > 4000;
```

Lateral joins make it simpler to define chains of calculations, because the next expression can depend on the previous one.

Of course, the traditional methods of using a CTE or subquery are also quite viable.